# How to mody and copy several files with python 35?

Tags: file, python-3.x, copy

I have this code portion for instance :

```
fichiers=glob.glob('/path/*.file')
for f in fichiers:
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        fichier = open(f,'r')
        for l in fichier:
            m = regex.match(l)
            if m:
                print('%s/ EMO /%s'%(m.group(1),m.group(3)))
            #here I want to write this modified line
            else:
                #write line non modified
        fichier.close()
```

And I would like, instead of printing results in the shell, apply the substitution to all lines of each line with copying files with new names or in a new directory (to be sure not making mistakes).
Have you some idea to teach me how to do that please ?

Answer (score 1):

It's really quite simple: all you need to do is define your output directory and open a new file in that directory to write to, every time you open a file that you read. Check this out:

```
import glob
import os

outdirpath = "/path/to/output/directory"

for fpath in glob.glob('/path/*.file'):
    if not os.path.isfile(fpath): continue
    with open(fpath) as fichier, open(os.path.join(outdirpath, os.path.basename(fpath)), 'w') as outfile:
        for line in fichier:
            m = regex.match(line)
            if m:
                outfile.write('%s/ EMO /%s'%(m.group(1),m.group(3)))
            else:
                outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Nice answer, but `f` is not defined.

Comment: Thank you but... f is a file in fpath ? Should I do :

    for fpath in fichiers:
        for f in fpath:
            if os.path.isfile(f):

Comment: @H.eyXD: you're right! I should be more careful when I copy-paste code :P